# How I can get do NSString object from JSON data

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I'm iOS Beginner, and I have some troubles with coding.
By sending ASIHTTPRequest:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?geocode=37.781157,-122.398720,25km"];
```

I receive data like this:

```
            {
        "created_at" = "Fri, 25 Jan 2013 17:48:29 +0000";
        "from_user" = "ZacHWallS_SBI";
        "from_user_id" = 252712138;
        "from_user_id_str" = 252712138;
        "from_user_name" = "ZACH WALLS";
        geo = "<null>";
        id = 294864332490162176;
        "id_str" = 294864332490162176;
        "in_reply_to_status_id" = 294861687004225537;
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str" = 294861687004225537;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        location = "BAY AREA CALIFORNIA";
        metadata =             {
            "result_type" = recent;
        };
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3029389178/e3567459d147bc5d0a10f3c797b477aa_normal.png";
        "profile_image_url_https" = "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3029389178/e3567459d147bc5d0a10f3c797b477aa_normal.png";
        source = "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/#!/download/ipad&quot;&gt;Twitter for iPad&lt;/a&gt;";
        text = "@LilTioSBi yee ima slide through prolly";
        "to_user" = LilTioSBi;
        "to_user_id" = 35629694;
        "to_user_id_str" = 35629694;
        "to_user_name" = "Nevin Tio";
    },
```

Next I do this:

```
-(void) requestFinished: (ASIHTTPRequest *) request {
NSString *theJSON = [request responseString];
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *jsonDictionary = [parser objectWithString:theJSON];
//NSLog(@"\n\n%@", jsonDictionary);  
NSMutableArray *userName = [userinfo objectForKey:@"from_user"];
NSLog(@"\n\n\n%@",userName);
```

I need to capture "from_user".
Then run, and compiler says: [__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x755bbc0...
How do it correctly?

Comment: nslog(..., jsonDictionary) worked ?

Comment: NSLog jsonDictionary and study the output.  (This is actually a simple case in that you have one large dictionary with only one small embedded inner dictionary.)  Write the code to extract the "from_user" element from the dictionary.  Refer to the NSDictionary spec on the Apple web site to find out how to do this.

Comment: But the error message you're getting indicates that you didn't show us all of the JSON.  There is apparently an outer array that you must traverse first.  Look at the NSLog of the output from objectWithString.  Is it an NSDictionary, or is there an NSArray surrounding some NSDictionaries??

Comment: And ***PLEASE*** next time do a few searches of SO and study some of the other answers.  This is the same question we see several times a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'll be begin by clarifying something, which is that it's actually the runtime that is giving you the "[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x755bbc0" error.

Let's break it down:

`__NSArrayM` sounds suspiciously like `NSArray` (`NSArray` is technically something called a class cluster, meaning you won't always see exactly `NSArray` in practice, just something that works like one).

`-objectForKey:` is a method on `NSDictionary`

So, we're calling a method on an array that we think is a dictionary (calling a method = sending a message, or "selector" in ObjC parlance).

It seems like you've omitted some of your code, but if you just passed the value from something like:

```
[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"results"]
```

You would end up with an array of tweets. You then need to grab an item from that array to get at its `from_user` key.

```
NSArray *tweets = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *username = [tweet objectForKey:@"from_user"];
```

Comment: Well explained answer. Note that `__NSArrayM` is the internal class name for a mutable array. `__NSArrayI` is for the immutable variant. The `NSArray` class cluster is fascinating if you delve into it :-).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
NSString *userName = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"from_user"];
```

Comment: `from_user` is not an array. And it will certainly not be a mutable one.

Comment: I dint get you, I passed a 'key' not the array.

Comment: The value for the key, `from_user`, is a string not an array. It is certainly not mutable either.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you have an array of tweets. So:

```
- (void) requestFinished: (ASIHTTPRequest *) request {
    NSString *theJSON = [request responseString];
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSArray *parsedJson = [parser objectWithString:theJSON];

    NSMutableArray *allFromUsers = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSDictionary *tweet in parsedJson) {
        NSString *fromUser = [tweet objectForKey:@"from_user"];
        [allFromUsers addObject:fromUser];
    }
    NSLog(@"allFromUsers = %@", allFromUsers);

    // ... etc ...
}
```

Or just grab the individual tweet you want out of the `parsedJson` array.

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
NSMutableArray *userName = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"from_user"]];
```

Or maybe you just want to put the name in a NSString?

```
NSString *userName = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"from_user"];
```